# connection to remote mongodb server failed in golang, giving authentication error

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to connect to remote mongodb server in golang and adding data in database. Its giving me error as follows:
server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed.

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
    "log"
    // "os"
)

type Person struct {
    Name  string
    Phone string
}

func main() {

    session, err := mgo.Dial("mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds041154.mongolab.com:41154/location")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Session created")
    }

    // Optional. Switch the session to a monotonic behavior.
    session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

    c := session.DB("location").C("people")
    err = c.Insert(&Person{"Ale", "+55 53 8116 9639"},
        &Person{"Cla", "+55 53 8402 8510"})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    result := Person{}
    err = c.Find(bson.M{"name": "Ale"}).One(&result)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Phone:", result.Phone)

}
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Are you *sure* your credentials are correct? No trailing spaces/formatting from copying it into your editor? Note that your program just continues if there's an error connecting to the driver (it should probably be `log.Fatal(err)` in that instance)

Comment: i have not put credentials in code but <dbuser>:<dbpassword> are username and password. I got this format 'mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds041154.mongolab.com:41154/location' by creating mongodb online.

Comment: @elithrar My credentials are also correct but I'm getting `auth failed` error calling `mgo.Dial`

Answer (score 6):

I was getting similar error, but I found that I had entered wrong login credentials.

This code worked for me:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
)

//const MongoDb details
const (
    hosts      = "ds026491.mongolab.com:26491"
    database   = "messagingdb"
    username   = "admin"
    password   = "youPassword"
    collection = "messages"
)

func main() {

    info := &mgo.DialInfo{
        Addrs:    []string{hosts},
        Timeout:  60 * time.Second,
        Database: database,
        Username: username,
        Password: password,
    }

    session, err1 := mgo.DialWithInfo(info)
    if err1 != nil {
        panic(err1)
    }

    col := session.DB(database).C(collection)

    count, err2 := col.Count()
    if err2 != nil {
        panic(err2)
    }
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Messages count: %d", count))
}
```

It is also on [Github](https://github.com/Velkata/Golang-MongoDB3.0-Example)

Answer (score 4):

You need to call [.Login(user, pass string)](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Database.Login) on the database you need to authenticate with:

```
if err:= session.DB(authDB).Login(user, pass); err != nil {
  panic(err)
}
```

Note that this authenticates the `session`, so each other session you [.Copy()](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Session.Copy) or [.Clone()](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Session.Clone) from it is also authenticated.